# Python Confusion Matrix Length

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to evaluate the accuracy and performance of several KNN Classifiers.

```py
DataTest["ConfM_K30_ST"] = confusion_matrix(
    DataTest["ST_Class"], 
    DataTest["KNN_K30_ST"]
    )        

aux = DataTest["ST_Class"]
aux1 = DataTest["KNN_K30_ST"]
```

When trying to compare the Predicted Result with the Originals I receive the following error:

`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

`DataTest` is my DataFrame containing 20% of the Data. The labeled data is, for this example, `"ST_Class"` and the predicted data is `"KNN_K30_ST"`.

In order to verify what was going on I set these 2 dataframes on aux and aux1. They are both of type `Series` with `sizes (3224,)`.

The only problem I could see is that the indexes are not continuous and don't start in 0 nor end in 3223. To facilitate comprehension see the image below.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5OOh.png

Comment: If DataTest is a pandas dataframe than you cannot assign a confusion matrix to a column because by definition the confusion matrix will be 2 dimensional. You can use ```pandas.crosstab``` to generate a confusion matrix between true and predicted values. You can also use reset index to compare to same length series.

Comment: Right, I was so focused on the series length I ignored the obvious, thank you @iamchoosinganame. Can you help me close the question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error I can see is that you are trying to store the `confusion matrix` as a `column` in the `dataframe`. This isn't possible due to the size mismatch.

Here's a small sample

```
df1
   a
0  1
2  1
4  1

df2
   a
1  0
3  1
5  0

# Output from the confusion matrix
confusion_matrix(df1, df2)
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I was obliviously trying to store a confusion matrix in a DataFrame.
My solution was to set it in a Dictionary.

Thank you all for the quick replies!